# Stripe multiple pays at once

Tags: node.js, stripe-payments

I have a situation in which want to pay multiple sellers at once from a buyer. Basically when the shopper selects different products from different sellers, but when the user checkouts, the shopper only needs to key in their credit card info once but at the backend, logic will charge and transfer based on seller stripe info (stripe fees will also be charged from seller). Sellers could be multiple in a single checkout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a use case for the [seperate charges and transfers](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/separate-charges-and-transfers) flow. You effectively take payment on your platform then send transfers to each seller connected account according to their share of the transaction.